# Help identifying likely Star Wars Set

Tags: set-identification

I bought some LEGO in bulk and would love some help identifying what ship/craft these pieces might belong to. Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 11):

That's part [x1435 Flag 5x6 Hexagonal](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=x1435). In colour Dark Red it appears in four Star Wars sets, but only one of them has the stickers: set [75135-1 Obi-Wan's Jedi Interceptor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=75135-1).

[image: Set image]

Comment: Thanks so much, Ivan. Seems we are missing the main pod section! Cheers :)